# allow scroll through existing records, but prohibit addition of new records

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form in Access which is designed to allow the user to make changes to existing records, but I don't want them to be able to add a record.  Is there a setting for this, or do I need code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can open the form in design mode and under the **Data** tab of the form's property sheet set the **AllowAdditions** property to No.

Comment: Thanks.  I knew it was simple, but couldn't find it.